# Using ‘&’ in POST variables

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ajax post special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954502/ajax-post-special-characters)

I am building my own post parameters and passing them via ajax; however, my POST contains an `&` symbol. How can I post these and escape the special characters so it posts as text only and doesn't split up my value?

Ex:

```
Thing=lala&lalala
```

Should be `thing = 'lala&lalala'` but what I get is `thing = 'lala'` and `='lalala'` where the second key is blank.

Comment: @FelixKling Apologies. Didn't see that one in my searches.

Answer (score 6):

You should use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your parameters before sending them to the server. It will properly escape everything in your parameters.

**Quick example:**

```
var s = 'Thing=' + encodeURIComponent('lala&lalala');
```

Please note that every value should be encoded separately (so you should not simply use it on the whole query string).

Comment: +1. Damned, you're right, I confused myself. `encodeURIComponent` is the right one.